# Convert 'Control' to textbox and assign it a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am trying to create a form. The form controls names are always going to be the same. However the type of control will change. For example, I have a control named "first_name". When the page is initialized, it retrieves data from a database stating what the type of control (TextBox, DropDownList or CheckBox); Then the form is dynamically created on the page. To keep the viewstate, I created the control in the OnInit method.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Control first_name;
    string ControlType = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
    switch (ControlType)
    {
        case("TextBox"):
            first_name = new Control() as TextBox; first_name.ID = "first_name"; this.Controls.Add(first_name);
            break;
        case("DropDownList"):
            first_name = new Control() as DropDownList; first_name.ID = "first_name"; this.Controls.Add(first_name);
            break;
        case("CheckBox"):
            first_name = new Control() as CheckBox; first_name.ID = "first_name"; this.Controls.Add("first_name");
            break;
    }
}
```

Then I render the control to the page.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write("first_name: ");
    first_name.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

Next, I try to assign values to the control. This is where I run into problems. I know that when it's declared globally, it is declared as a control and holds those values.

Is there a way to declare it globally from within a function or to change the type of a control after it's been declared globally?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (first_name.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case ("TextBox"):
            first_name.Text = "Your First Name...";
            break;
        case ("DropDownList"):
            first_name.Items.Add("Jason");
            first_name.Items.Add("Kelly");
            first_name.Items.Add("Keira");
            first_name.Items.Add("Sandi");
            first_name.Items.Add("Gary");
            break;
        case ("CheckBox"):
            first_name.Checked = true;
            break;
    }        
}
```

Please provide a way that I can accomplish this.

Comment: -1 for the question since the code is far from even compilable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `OnInit` you should do `new TextBox()` and not `new Control() as TextBox` since the second will just return `null`.

Your `Page_Load` would be something like this:

```
if (first_name is TextBox)
    ((TextBox)first_name).Text = "Your First Name...";
else if (first_name is DropDownList)
{
    var drp = (DropDownList)first_name;
    drp.Items.Add();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the type specific properties, you'll need to cast `first_name` to the appropriate type within your switch/case statement.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (first_name.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case ("TextBox"):
            (first_name as TextBox).Text = "Your First Name...";
            break;
        case ("DropDownList"):
            (first_name as DropDownList).Items.Add("Jason");
            (first_name as DropDownList).Items.Add("Kelly");
            (first_name as DropDownList).Items.Add("Keira");
            (first_name as DropDownList).Items.Add("Sandi");
            (first_name as DropDownList).Items.Add("Gary");
            break;
        case ("CheckBox"):
            (first_name as CheckBox).Checked = true;
            break;
    }        
}
```

Comment: does not work since GetType().ToString() returns the full type name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Control` as the static type, and use another variable in each `case`:

```
Control ctrl;
switch(type)
{
  case "TextBox":
    var box = new TextBox();
    box.Text = "...";
    ctrl = box;
    break;
}
Page.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Apparently - looking at the overridden `Render` method - you're doing a lot of stuff by hand that ASP.NET Web Forms do for you. You can simply add `ctrl` (or any control) to the `Page`'s `Controls` collection.

The `Page.Render` methods renders all elements of the `Controls` collection, unless you override it.

Comment: quote from the question: "When the page is initialized, it retrieves data from a database stating what the type of control (TextBox, DropDownList or CheckBox);" - he is creating dynamic controls, not static

Comment: @Knaģis Oh, I see, I corrected my answer. Looked too much into the code rather than the question.